# How to compile html form template to html string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, render

I have a object like this:

```
$scope.item ={
        fieldName:'First Name',
        fieldModel:'user.firstname',
        placeholder:'enter your name'
    }
```

and I want to compile this html form template like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="input.html">
    <div class="items form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            {{item.fieldName}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" ng-model="{{item.fieldModel}}" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

to html string that use pure html design:

```
<div class="items form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
         First Name
     </label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder="enter your name" class="form-control">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your template with:

```
<div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="input.html"></div>
```

but your template should be:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="input.html">
<div class="items form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        {{item.fieldName}}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.fieldModel" placeholder="{{item.placeholder}}" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't understand my means. I wan to create html generator with angularjs. I want to generate html that copyable like this http://bootsnipp.com/forms